# Swift 2 OAuth with Instagram can't open the Instagram app

Tags: ios, oauth, swift2, instagram-api

Im trying to access the Instagram app from my own iOS for OAuth registration. I have the following code and it is working to access Instagram via Safari, but I would like the app to open if it is on the phone. Also looking for a way to get an authentication token from Instagram for my app.

Here is my code:

```
func startOAuth2Login()
{
....
    let authPath:String = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=\(clientID)&redirect_uri=grokInstagram://?aParam=paramVal&response_type=code"

    var instagramHooks = "instagram://app"
    var instagramUrl = NSURL(string: instagramHooks)

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramUrl!)
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramUrl!)


    } else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
        print("didn't have it")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: authPath)!)
    }
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 9 has made a small change to the handling of URL scheme. You must whitelist the url's that your app will call out to using the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in your `Info.plist`.

[image]

More here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html

Comment: Do you know how I can get an Authorization Token back from the app for OAuth2 and return to my app?

Comment: I'm not master in OAuth. But I believe that after going back to your app , the needed information in here `Appdelegate.h`

`func application(app: UIApplication, 
    openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {`
Please check it.


More about Instagram API:https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/